# Linux headers for kernel 5.4.20

Tags: kernel, linux-headers

I have an old ODROID U3 board running Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.4.20. I want to setup a wireguard VPN server on it, but it turns out that wireguard needs linux headers for this kernel. The `uname -r` outputs `5.4.20-stb-exy+` . I cannot find any relevant ubuntu package for it. If the headers do not exist anywhere, is it possible somehow to compile them and how?

Comment: This seems like a great question for https://forum.odroid.com/, manufacturer support venue for that hardware.

Comment: That doesn't look like a Ubuntu kernel, I don't find any reference on launchpad for it so you'll have to go to it's creators  (they should have the source code to enable you to compile your own as well).

Comment: @user535733 Problem is that board is EOL and no longer supported, so that's why I was looking if there's any way to compile headers that's appropriate in such cases, and what exactly I need to look for to do this.